# How do I keep these images constrained properly?

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I need to have a lot of different images set in a specific way in a layout. So far, it seems the best way to do this is using a ConstraintLayout. However, nothing seems to want to stay where it should.

This is an image of how the ImageViews currently look in the XML, but they don't have any constraints and they change position whenever I try and constrain them.
ImageViews

[image]

Here's the XML code I have written. I've taken out the constraints to try and help make it more understandable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MapFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgClare"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="261dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_clare"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="43dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="350dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgGalwayWest"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="348dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_galway_west"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-13dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="279dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgGalwayEast"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="302dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_galway_east"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="96dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="253dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMayo"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="322dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_mayo"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-21dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="216dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCorkSouthWest"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_cork_south_west"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="11dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="600dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgKerry"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="165dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_kerry_cut"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="513dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgWicklow"
        android:layout_width="84dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_wicklow"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="308dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="439dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgWexford"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="285dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_wexford"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgWaterford"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="113dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_waterford"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="195dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="594dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDonegal"
        android:layout_width="205dp"
        android:layout_height="560dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_donegal"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="96dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-88dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="0dp"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLimerickCity"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_limerick_city"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="277dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="263dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLimerickCounty"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_limerick_county"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="513dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCorkNorthWest"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_cork_north_west"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="112dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="548dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCorkEast"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_cork_east"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="590dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCorkNorthCentral"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_cork_north_central"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="171dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="611dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCorkSouthCentral"
        android:layout_width="39dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_cork_south_central"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="186dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="627dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCarlowKilkenny"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="207dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_carlow_kilkenny"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="236dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="487dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/imgWexford"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTipperary"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_tipperary"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="394dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgKildareSouth"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="247dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_kildare_south"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="264dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="372dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLaoisOffaly"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_laois_offaly"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgCorkNorthWest"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgWexford"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgGalwayEast"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgLongfordWestmeath" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgKildareNorth"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_kildare_north"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="293dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="428dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMeathWest"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_meath_west"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="231dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="394dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLongfordWestmeath"
        android:layout_width="101dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_longford_westmeath"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="186dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="372dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgCavanMonoghan"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_cavan_monoghan"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="188dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="234dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgMeathEast"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_meath_east"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="288dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="366dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLouth"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_louth"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imgKildareNorth"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgDonegal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSligoLeitrim"
        android:layout_width="117dp"
        android:layout_height="126dp"
        android:src="@drawable/constituency_sligo_leitirim"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="89dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="269dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

xml property `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX` and `tools:layout_editor_absoluteY` is used for layout editor in Android Studio only, it has no influence on view positioning. Essence of `ConstraintLayout` is to describe connections and position views in relation to each other. I.e you define view A, set it's position to parent, set it margins- then describe position of it's sibling view B, using view A as base, and so on.
There are lot of articles about working with constraint layout, like https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013 
And don't bother visual editor, it's misleading at best.